# procedure created but not executing

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create or replace procedure para_cursor_exe as 
cursor c_p_det(tar_val number) is select name, salary from fees where salary < tar_val;
nname varchar2(30);
ssalary number(5);

begin 
<<block_exe>>
begin
Open c_p_det(&tar_val);
LOOP
FETCH c_p_det into nname, ssalary;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NAME : ' || NNAME || ' :::: SALARY : ' || SSALARY);
EXIT WHEN C_P_DET%NOTFOUND;
END LOOP;
CLOSE C_P_DET;
end;

execute immediate ' block_exe ' ;
dbms_output.put_line('done processing !!');

end;
/  

SQL> @para_cursor_exe.sql;
Enter value for tar_val: 1000
old   9:  Open c_p_det(&tar_val);
new   9:  Open c_p_det(1000);

Procedure created.
```

The procedure is compiled but on call gives an error as follows

```
SQL> call para_cursor_exe;
call para_cursor_exe
 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06576: not a valid function or procedure name
```

i wanna process the procedure dynamically for different target values which are supposed to be passed to the cursor at runtime. How do i call it or is the logic wrong?

Comment: Please do not ignore the suggestion you get to add a specific DBMS tag when using the SQL tag. Knowing which database you're using is necessary, because syntax and functionality is vastly different between them.

Comment: @Ken White.. I'm using oracle and running from command prompt.

Comment: Yes, I know. I added the Oracle tag for you. You should have added it yourself when prompted to do so when asking your question, instead of ignoring the red box that appeared saying you should add it.

Comment: Are you sure procedure is compiled successfully?

Comment: @Nitish.... yes totally.... get the msg  'procedure created'...

Comment: edited the post with the compile message...

Comment: @Ken White  done ... new here... will make it a point next time

Comment: In SQL\*Plus you need `exec`, **not** `call` if I'm not mistaken

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name tried that too but no go again... same error...        SQL> exec para_cursor_exe;
BEGIN para_cursor_exe; END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.PARA_CURSOR_EXE", line 18
ORA-06512: at line 1

Comment: apologies for not getting the edit correct...

Comment: can anyone resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The error states that **call** is not not a valid function or procedure name.

```
create or replace procedure p as begin null; end;
/
```

---

Use **call** with parenthesis - `()`

```
call p();
```

or don't use **call** at all

```
begin
    p;
end;
```

Comment: had tried both the options even before askin here and tried again but no go... error persists.. get a new error 'invalid sql statement'

Comment: This is probably because your code is invalid. `select * from all_errors;`

Comment: IF the code is invalid then how does it compile right? n what should i do to get it working?